# Error 502 Bad Gateway When Using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, http, codeigniter

The following code is run from my controller and causes a 502 error bad gateway on one server. I have been unable to reproduce on my server. What are some causes of 502 Bad Gateway?

```
function index()
{
    $this->_reload();
}

function _reload($data=array())
{
    $person_info = $this->Employee->get_logged_in_employee_info();
    $data['cart']=$this->sale_lib->get_cart();
    $data['modes']=array('sale'=>$this->lang->line('sales_sale'),'return'=>$this->lang->line('sales_return'));
    $data['mode']=$this->sale_lib->get_mode();
    $data['items_in_cart'] = $this->sale_lib->get_items_in_cart();
    $data['subtotal']=$this->sale_lib->get_subtotal();
    $data['taxes']=$this->sale_lib->get_taxes();
    $data['total']=$this->sale_lib->get_total();
    $data['items_module_allowed'] = $this->Employee->has_permission('items', $person_info->person_id);
    $data['comment'] = $this->sale_lib->get_comment();
    $data['email_receipt'] = $this->sale_lib->get_email_receipt();
    $data['payments_total']=$this->sale_lib->get_payments_total();
    $data['amount_due']=$this->sale_lib->get_amount_due();
    $data['payments']=$this->sale_lib->get_payments();
    $data['payment_options']=array(
        $this->lang->line('sales_cash') => $this->lang->line('sales_cash'),
        $this->lang->line('sales_check') => $this->lang->line('sales_check'),
        $this->lang->line('sales_giftcard') => $this->lang->line('sales_giftcard'),
        $this->lang->line('sales_debit') => $this->lang->line('sales_debit'),
        $this->lang->line('sales_credit') => $this->lang->line('sales_credit')
    );

    $customer_id=$this->sale_lib->get_customer();
    if($customer_id!=-1)
    {
        $info=$this->Customer->get_info($customer_id);
        $data['customer']=$info->first_name.' '.$info->last_name;
        $data['customer_email']=$info->email;
    }
    $data['payments_cover_total'] = $this->_payments_cover_total();
    $this->load->view("sales/register",$data);
}
```

Comment: What version CI are you using?

Comment: 1.7.3 on an NGNIX server

Comment: If I can make any error happen such as sending output before a session happens, it will actually make the page work (with the error message). Something strange is going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems setcookie was being called too much was caused the 502 error. I am not sure if NGNIX was a limit, but this solved the problem.

Comment: I was my problem too, I didn't notice that my cookie saving line was in a loop, thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

It's an NGINX/CI problem, if you can't change the settings then changing the session to database worked for me

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a buggy Encrypt library.  Try setting:

```
$config[‘sess_encrypt_cookie’] = FALSE;
```

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/103453/#807036